# SQL Nested Query to select in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My database has two tables.

food_table:

```
+----+----------+---------------+
| ID | NAME     | NutrientID    |
+----+----------+---------------+
```

nutrient_table:

```
+------------+--------------+
| NutrientID | NutrientName |
+------------+--------------+
```

I want select all rows in food table, but get NutrientName instead of nutrientID.
If I do:

```
select * from food_table.
```

I will get NutrientID. Is it possible to get NutrientName in a single query?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT f.*, n.NutrientName FROM food_table f
LEFT JOIN nutrient_table n
ON n.NutrientID = f.NutrientID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a join inner to tables filtering by field NutrientID , if you look this field as the same in two table and the join works fine.